# Excel VBA If range.value = something then fills Columns G

Tags: excel, vba

For example

if range A14:A200

if A14 = 1 so fill G14 Ok
if A14 = 1 so fill G14 Ok
and so on

For example
if range A14:A200
if A14 = 1 so fill G14 Ok
if A15 = 1 so fill G15 Ok
and so on

Answer (score 3):

you could use the excel formulas:

```
Sub IFSomething()

    With Range("A14:A200") reference the needed range
        With .Offset(, 6) ' reference the cells 6 columns to the right of referenced range
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-6]=1,""OK"","""")" ' place a formula in referenced range
            .Value = .Value ' leave only values
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is revise solution I hope this resolve your query.

```
Sub If_loop_test()

Dim x As Integer
    
For x = 1 To 200
  
    If Range("A" & x).Value = 1 Then
    Range("G" & x).Value = "ok"
    End If
Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively clean and versatile version.
Remember if you're going to be applying this to large data sets this might be slow. you can fix this by importing the range into an array and iterating through that. your code will go from taking 10 seconds on very large data sets to under a second.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub If_Offset_Value()
    
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim RG As Range
    Dim CL As Range
    Dim CheckVal As Variant
    
    ' > Change this to whatever value you're checking for.
    CheckVal = 1
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("My WorkSheet Name")
    Set RG = WS.Range("A14:A200")
    
    For Each CL In RG.Cells
        If CL.Value = CheckVal Then
        
            ' > Couple of options here depending on your needs:
            '   Both options give you the same result, but Offset
            '   moves left and right if you change RG column,
            '   whereas column letter referense will stay G
            
            '1) Offset Method
            CL.Offset(0, 6).Value = "OK"
            
            '2) Reference Column Letter
            WS.Range("G" & CL.Row).Value = "OK"
            
        End If
    Next CL
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
End Sub
```